# Create groups from vector of 0,1 and NA

Tags: r

Background:

I'm trying to strip out a corpus where the speaker is identified. I've reduced the problem of removing a particular speaker from the corpuse to the following stream of 1,0, and NA (x). 0 means that person is speaking, 1 someone else is speaking, NA means that whoever was the last speaker is still speaking.

Here's a visual example:

```
0  1 S0: Hello, how are you today?
1  2 S1: I'm great thanks for asking!
NA 3 I'm a little tired though!
0  4 S0: I'm sorry to hear that. Are you ready for our discussion?
1  5 S1: Yes, I have everything I need.
NA 7 Let's begin.
```

So from this frame, I'd like to take 2,3,5, and 7. Or,. I would like the result to be 0,1,1,0,1,1.

How do I pull the positions of each run of 1 and NA up to the position before the next 0 in a vector.

Here is an example, and my desired output:

Example input:

```
x <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,0,1,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,0)
```

Example output:

These are the positions that I want because they identify that "speaker 1" is talking (1, or 1 followed by NA up to the next 0)

```
pos <- c(6,8,9,10,11,15,16,17)
```

An alternative output would be a filling:

```
fill <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
```

Where the NA values of the previous 1 or 0 are filled up to the next new value.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding exactly how you're getting your desired `pos` vector. Could you explain a little more exactly what you want?

Comment: I tried to update it with a visual example of my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s <- which(x==1);
e <- c(which(x!=1),length(x)+1L);
unlist(Map(seq,s,e[findInterval(s,e)+1L]-1L));
## [1]  6  8  9 10 11 15 16 17
```

Every occurrence of a 1 in the input vector is the *start* of a sequence of position indexes applicable to speaker 1. We capture this in `s` with `which(x==1)`.

For each start index, we must find the length of its containing sequence. The length is determined by the closest forward occurrence of a 0 (or, more generally, any non-NA value other than 1, if such was possible). Hence, we must first compute `which(x!=1)` to get these indexes. Because the final occurrence of a 1 may not have a forward occurrence of a 0, we must append an extra virtual index one unit past the end of the input vector, which is why we must call `c()` to combine `length(x)+1L`. We store this as `e`, reflecting that these are (potential) *end* indexes. Note that these are *exclusive* end indexes; they are not actually part of the (potential) preceding speaker 1 sequence.

Finally, we must generate the actual sequences. To do this, we must make one call to `seq()` for each element of `s`, also passing its corresponding end index from `e`. To find the end index we can use `findInterval()` to find the index into `e` whose element value (that is, the end index into `x`) falls just *before* each respective element of `s`. (The reason why it is just *before* is that the algorithm used by `findInterval()` is `v[i[j]] ≤ x[j] < v[i[j]+1]` as explained on the [doc](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html) page.) We must then add one to it to get the index into `e` whose element value falls just *after* each respective element of `s`. We then index `e` with it, giving us the end indexes into `x` that follow each respective element of `s`. We must subtract one from that because the sequence we generate must exclude the (exclusive) end element. The easiest way to make the calls to `seq()` is to `Map()` the two endpoint vectors to it, returning a list of each sequence, which we can `unlist()` to get the required output.

---

```
s <- which(!is.na(x));
rep(c(0,x[s]),diff(c(1L,s,length(x)+1L)));
## [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

Every occurrence of a non-NA value in the input vector is the *start* of a segment which, in the output, must become a repetition of the element value at that start index. We capture these indexes in `s` with `which(!is.na(x));`.

We must then repeat each start element a sufficient number of times to reach the following segment. Hence we can call `rep()` on `x[s]` with a vectorized `times` argument whose values consist of `diff()` called on `s`. To handle the final segment, we must append an index one unit past the end of the input vector, `length(x)+1L`. Also, to deal with the possible case of NAs leading the input vector, we must prepend a 0 to `x[s]` and a 1 to the `diff()` argument, which will repeat 0 a sufficient number of times to cover the leading NAs, if such exist.

---

## Benchmarking (Position)

```
library(zoo);
library(microbenchmark);
library(stringi);

marat <- function(x) { v <- na.locf(zoo(x)); index(v)[v==1]; };
rawr <- function(x) which(zoo::na.locf(c(0L, x))[-1L] == 1L);
jota1 <- function(x) { stringx <- paste(x, collapse = ""); stringx <- gsub("NA", "N", stringx, fixed = TRUE); while(grepl("(?<=1)N", stringx, perl = TRUE)) stringx <- gsub("(?<=1)N", "1", stringx, perl = TRUE); unlist(gregexpr("1", stringx)); };
jota2 <- function(x) { stringx <- paste(x, collapse = ""); stringx <- gsub("NA", "N", stringx, fixed = TRUE); while(grepl("(?<=1)N", stringx, perl = TRUE)) stringx <- gsub("(?<=1)N", "1", stringx, perl = TRUE); newx <-unlist(strsplit(stringx, "")); which(newx == 1); };
jota3 <- function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- "N"; stringx <- stri_flatten(x); ones <- stri_locate_all_regex(stringx, "1N*")[[1]]; unlist(lapply(seq_along(ones[, 1]), function(ii) seq.int(ones[ii, "start"], ones[ii, "end"]))); };
bgoldst <- function(x) { s <- which(x==1); e <- c(which(x!=1),length(x)+1L); unlist(Map(seq,s,e[findInterval(s,e)+1L]-1L)); };
```

---

```
## OP's test case
x <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,0,1,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,0);

ex <- marat(x);
identical(ex,rawr(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,jota1(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,jota2(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,jota3(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,bgoldst(x));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(marat(x),rawr(x),jota1(x),jota2(x),jota3(x),bgoldst(x));
## Unit: microseconds
##        expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
##    marat(x) 411.830 438.5580 503.24486 453.7400 489.2345 2299.915   100
##     rawr(x) 115.466 143.0510 154.64822 153.5280 163.7920  276.692   100
##    jota1(x) 448.180 469.7770 484.47090 479.6125 491.1595  835.633   100
##    jota2(x) 440.911 464.4315 478.03050 472.1290 484.3170  661.579   100
##    jota3(x)  53.885  65.4315  74.34808  71.2050  76.9785  158.232   100
##  bgoldst(x)  34.212  44.2625  51.54556  48.5395  55.8095  139.843   100
```

---

```
## scale test, high probability of NA
set.seed(1L);
N <- 1e5L; probNA <- 0.8; x <- sample(c(NA,T),N,T,c(probNA,1-probNA)); x[which(x)] <- rep(c(0,1),len=sum(x,na.rm=T));

ex <- marat(x);
identical(ex,rawr(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,jota1(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,jota2(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,jota3(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,bgoldst(x));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(marat(x),rawr(x),jota1(x),jota2(x),jota3(x),bgoldst(x));
## Unit: milliseconds
##        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
##    marat(x) 189.34479 196.70233 226.72926 233.39234 237.45738 293.95154   100
##     rawr(x)  24.46984  27.46084  43.91167  29.92112  68.86464  79.53008   100
##    jota1(x) 154.91450 157.09231 161.73505 158.18326 160.42694 206.04889   100
##    jota2(x) 149.47561 151.68187 155.92497 152.93682 154.79668 201.13302   100
##    jota3(x)  82.30768  83.89149  87.35308  84.99141  86.95028 129.94730   100
##  bgoldst(x)  80.94261  82.94125  87.80780  84.02107  86.10844 130.56440   100
```

---

```
## scale test, low probability of NA
set.seed(1L);
N <- 1e5L; probNA <- 0.2; x <- sample(c(NA,T),N,T,c(probNA,1-probNA)); x[which(x)] <- rep(c(0,1),len=sum(x,na.rm=T));

ex <- marat(x);
identical(ex,rawr(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,jota1(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,jota2(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,jota3(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,bgoldst(x));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(marat(x),rawr(x),jota1(x),jota2(x),jota3(x),bgoldst(x));
## Unit: milliseconds
##        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
##    marat(x) 178.93359 189.56032 216.68963 226.01940 234.06610 294.6927   100
##     rawr(x)  17.75869  20.39367  36.16953  24.44931  60.23612  79.5861   100
##    jota1(x) 100.10614 101.49238 104.11655 102.27712 103.84383 150.9420   100
##    jota2(x)  94.59927  96.04494  98.65276  97.20965  99.26645 137.0036   100
##    jota3(x) 193.15175 202.02810 216.68833 209.56654 227.94255 295.5672   100
##  bgoldst(x) 253.33013 266.34765 292.52171 292.18406 311.20518 387.3093   100
```

---

## Benchmarking (Fill)

```
library(microbenchmark);

bgoldst <- function(x) { s <- which(!is.na(x)); rep(c(0,x[s]),diff(c(1L,s,length(x)+1L))); };
user31264 <- function(x) { x[is.na(x)]=2; x.rle=rle(x); val=x.rle$v; if (val[1]==2) val[1]=0; ind = (val==2); val[ind]=val[which(ind)-1]; rep(val,x.rle$l); };
```

---

```
## OP's test case
x <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,0,1,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,0);

ex <- bgoldst(x);
identical(ex,user31264(x));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst(x),user31264(x));
## Unit: microseconds
##          expr    min     lq     mean median     uq    max neval
##    bgoldst(x) 10.264 11.548 14.39548 12.403 13.258 73.557   100
##  user31264(x) 31.646 32.930 35.74805 33.785 35.068 84.676   100
```

---

```
## scale test, high probability of NA
set.seed(1L);
N <- 1e5L; probNA <- 0.8; x <- sample(c(NA,T),N,T,c(probNA,1-probNA)); x[which(x)] <- rep(c(0,1),len=sum(x,na.rm=T));

ex <- bgoldst(x);
identical(ex,user31264(x));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst(x),user31264(x));
## Unit: milliseconds
##          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
##    bgoldst(x) 10.94491 11.21860 12.50473 11.53015 12.28945 50.25899   100
##  user31264(x) 17.18649 18.35634 22.50400 18.91848 19.53708 65.02668   100
```

---

```
## scale test, low probability of NA
set.seed(1L);
N <- 1e5L; probNA <- 0.2; x <- sample(c(NA,T),N,T,c(probNA,1-probNA)); x[which(x)] <- rep(c(0,1),len=sum(x,na.rm=T));

ex <- bgoldst(x);
identical(ex,user31264(x));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst(x),user31264(x));
## Unit: milliseconds
##          expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
##    bgoldst(x)  5.24815  6.351279  7.723068  6.635454  6.923264 45.04077   100
##  user31264(x) 11.79423 13.063710 22.367334 13.986584 14.908603 55.45453   100
```

Comment: Interesting. You know, I've been paid to write R code for over 7 years now and I still don't understand `findInterval()`. This seems to be the best answer of the bunch, but an explanation of your solution code could be useful for passerby.

Comment: @Jota Nice addition. Also added rawr's solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `na.locf` from the `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)
x <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,0,1,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,0)

v <- na.locf(zoo(x))
index(v)[v==1]
#[1]  6  8  9 10 11 15 16 17
```

Comment: For tabulation, do `tabulate(result,nbins = length(x))` where `result=index(v)[v==1]`

Comment: `which(zoo::na.locf(c(0L, x))[-1L] == 1L)` for about 4x faster

Comment: @rawr Added your solution to my benchmarks, nice addition.

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,0,1,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,0)
x[is.na(x)]=2
x.rle=rle(x)
val=x.rle$v
if (val[1]==2) val[1]=0
ind = (val==2)
val[ind]=val[which(ind)-1]
rep(val,x.rle$l)
```

Output:

```
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: I was also playing with a solution that used `rle` I couldn't quite get it sorted though. I like this idea though.

Answer (score 2):

Pasting the sequence into a string and using a while loop that checks (with `grep`) whether there are any `NA`s preceded by `1`s and substitutes (with `gsub`) such cases with a `1` will do it:

```
# substitute NA for "N" for later ease of processing and locating 1s by position
x[is.na(x)] <- "N"
# Collapse vector into a string
stringx <- paste(x, collapse = "")

while(grepl("(?<=1)N", stringx, perl = TRUE)) {
    stringx <- gsub("(?<=1)N", "1", stringx, perl = TRUE)
}
```

Then you can use `gregexpr` to get the indices of 1s.

```
unlist(gregexpr("1", stringx))
#[1]  6  8  9 10 11 15 16 17
```

Or you can split the string and look through to find the indices of 1s in the resulting vector:

```
newx <-unlist(strsplit(stringx, ""))
#[1] "N" "N" "N" "N" "0" "1" "0" "1" "1" "1" "1" "0" "N" "N" "1" "1" "1" "0"

which(newx == "1") 
#[1]  6  8  9 10 11 15 16 17
```

---

---

Using `stri_flatten` from the `stringi` package instead of `paste` and `stri_locate_all_fixed` rather than `gregexpr` or a string splitting route can provide a little bit more performance if it's a larger vector you're processing.  If the vector isn't large, no performance gains will result.

```
library(stringi)
x[is.na(x)] <- "N"
stringx <- stri_flatten(x)

while(grepl("(?<=1)N", stringx, perl = TRUE)) {
    stringx <- gsub("(?<=1)N", "1", stringx, perl = TRUE) 
}

stri_locate_all_fixed(stringx, "1")[[1]][,"start"]
```

---

The following approach is fairly straightforward and performs relatively well (based on bgoldst's excellent benchmarking example) on small and large samples (very well on bgoldst's  high probability of NA example)

```
x[is.na(x)] <- "N"
stringx <- stri_flatten(x)

ones <- stri_locate_all_regex(stringx, "1N*")[[1]]

#[[1]]
#
#     start end
#[1,]     6   6
#[2,]     8  11
#[3,]    15  17

unlist(lapply(seq_along(ones[, 1]),
    function(ii) seq.int(ones[ii, "start"], ones[ii, "end"])))
#[1]  6  8  9 10 11 15 16 17
```